# My app published but not showing in Playstore even by searching package name

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Recently about 20hours ago, I can published my application on playstore, after  lot of time it shows me that app has been successfully published, click to see it on playstore, I can simply click on it and check my app visibility and its fine, But it does not show me when I search it manually.

It can not show me even by searching through "Package name" / by putting complete url in search box / also not showing by searching developer name / even also not showing in my store. Simple mean is that only show when I can click on google play console published link.

App is already in production mode not in beta release.

Whats the problem is that?

Comment: In our case we had to wait 3 days, the app was in review. See https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/04/improving-update-process-with-your.html

Comment: did you solve it?